# remote debugging an ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging

I've got everything set up for remote debugging, when I attach to process my debugger shifts all my break points around.  I assume this is because the code base is different maybe?  What is the cause of this issue and how do I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code base was different just slightly after promotion - pulling the source from the server and running that solution resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the debug symbols from your local build to your remote server.

Comment: Or maybe build your application as debug, be sure to check "Emit debug info" and deploy to remote server.I recently do it same way and it works well.